# Multiple joins in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm starting with yii.

I have the following DB structure:

```
Table:             Rows:

user               [id,login,password,name,email]
userToProject      [user_id,project_id,role]
project            [id,name,status]
```

And I want to retrieve all the users working in a project with **status=3** as **role=manager**. And this is my code by the way, I need to make the second join to reach the project status.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join='INNER JOIN {{userToProject}} a ON t.id=a.user_id and a.role='.Role::MANAGER;
$criteria->distinct=true;
return User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Can I make it with a criteria or should I implement an SQLcommand and run it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you make relation in userToProject model like this...

```
'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id')

 //  after belongs_to User is a model class name..

'project'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'project_id'),

 //  after belongs_to Project is a model class name..
```

and then use active record like ..

```
$allrecord =  UserToProject::model()->with('user','project')->findAll(
                               'status = :status AND role = :role',
                                array(':status' => 3 , 'role' => 'manager'));

//in with bracket user , project is your relation name..
```

now in $allrecord you have all the record in array form...